# loading images or progress bar for typeahead in XPages

Tags: xpages, typeahead

I have created an Xpages then put a editbox in it. 
editbox has typeahead functionality. but some time It takes more than 5 seconds options to appear on editbox. During this 5 seconds i just want to make a loading progress screen on editbox or next to editbox.

is there any way to do this? any thought is important.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call a JavaScript function as soon the partial refresh of the typeahead is fired. A script to hijack the call can be found here: http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=416

A timer can wait for a specific amount of time (e.g. 1 second), and then show a progressbar if the refresh is still running. If the call is completed hide the image.

Feel free to create a snippet of your solution and post it as a XSnippet.

Comment: I tried and it worked well except one thing. I have big data more than 50.000 and i use ftSearch for typeahead. When i chose a value from the the list everything works well but after i push a value from typeahead and I delete  the value in inputbox an error is raising.
and then typeahead does not work. I need refresh the page. 
What  i would like to do is without refreshing the page i need to clear field and rework typehead. i am not sure how to do is CSJS

Comment: ' /*** overwrite error function ***/
  args["error"] = function()
{
      alert('Error raised!');
 };'